# Connection closed due to error Error: Unsupported protocol "undefined"

Tags: node.js, api, http

Hi guys i am new in nodejs when i am trying to run my node js file then Am getting an error like coneection closed due to error Error: Unsupported protocol "undefined" don't know where i am wrong please fix my error

https://ibb.co/31J6xWS

> index.js

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
var requests = require("requests");



const homeFile = fs.readFile("home.html", "utf-8",(err)=>{
    console.log("Sucessfully");
});

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.url == "/") {
        requests(
            "{API}",
            )
            .on("data", (chunk) =>{
                console.log(chunk);
            })
            .on("end", (err) => {
                if (err)
                    return console.log("coneection closed due to error",err);

                console.log("end");
            });
    }
})

server.listen(8000,"127.0.0.1")
```

Comment: Try avoiding screenshot. Instead, copy paste the error text into your question.

Comment: What is `"{API}"`?

Answer (score 3):

You have made a mistake in your pasting API key. Check your API key it will not be like URL.

`http://` is missing at the beginning.

Add `http://` in the start of your API key.

Answer (score 1):

Are u trying to use a template literal on line 13... the "{API}" section. If so it should `${API}` with backticks. And you need to import it from the file you have it in. Beginner to Node.js as well, and I have used something similar to this. Hope it helps. Have u seen https://www.npmjs.com/package/request? Might help you.

Comment: i know bro api should be ${API}

Comment: Or it could be simply `API`, there is no need to use template literals. @user13427179, have you checked the app with the updated API variable? The error is coming from the `requests` library, so it seems that's the cause.

Comment: Ah that could be it @Zsolt Meszaros, no need for template literal, just simply calling the variable, it just hasn't been defined has it

Answer (score 0):

a better and easier way to build a server is by using Express.js library you can download it with the following command:

```
npm i express
```

more information: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express

after that you can build a server very easily with the following code :

```
// npm install express
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res)=> {
  res.send('Hello World');
}) 

app.listen(3000,()=>{
 console.log("starting...");
});
```

the following code is create a server listening on *localhost* port 3000 and print a message **hello world**

Comment: i know how to create server using express js but here i am try to learning nodejs

Comment: the build-in module http in node.js has some down sides the express.js fix so there's no point in learning it, and working with express.js is considering as node.js learning

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem. Here is the solution. Replace {API} with your API key.

```
requests("replace this with your API url and API key")
```